# Handle Quotation Marks Importing From CSV

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, csv, delimiter

I'm importing around 30000 rows from a CSV file but I'm having an issue with importing when the user has inputted quotation marks. I already had an issue with when the user had inputted commas (I'm using a comma as a delimiter) but now I have an even bigger issue, one that I can't seem to find.

This is what I'm using so far ;

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select((field, index) => (dataTable.Columns[index].DataType == _datetype) ? ((DateTime)field).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") :
(field.ToString().Contains(",") ? "\"" + field.ToString() + "\"" : field.ToString()));
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
```

The column (in notepad++) looks like this;

```
"DIY Test, Test"
```

However when I open the table in MySQL it's been imported like this;

```
DIY Test, Test"
```

I.E it's now missing a quotation mark. This then messes up the import and the columns end up all over the place! I assume this has something to do with how I am handling commas and quotation marks, how can I avoid this case too?

The original text in the FoxPro file simply looks like;

`DIY Test, Test`

With no quotation marks! Just the comma. My class to use the `MySQLBulkLoader` looks like this;

```
    public void WriteToMySQL(string mySqlTable)
    {
        MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(mysqlConstr);
        mysqlCon.Open();
        string tempCsvFileSpec = @"C:\Users\DanD\Desktop\test.csv";
        var msbl = new MySqlBulkLoader(mysqlCon);
        msbl.TableName = "sdcdatabase." + mySqlTable;
        msbl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
        msbl.FileName = tempCsvFileSpec;
        msbl.FieldTerminator = ",";
        msbl.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
        msbl.Load();
        File.Delete(tempCsvFileSpec);
    }
```

Is using the `FieldTerminator` and the `FieldQuotationCharacter` like this wrong?

EDIT: added whole row for Danny;

```
21,630,459,462,0,Test                         ,1996-08-02,14:45:04  ,2,Test   ,"DIY Test, Test                                                                       "
```

Comment: _The column (in notepad++) looks like this_. What does the full row look like?

Comment: @Danny_ds Updated my question Danny

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the CSV importer that's built into .NET in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace called `TextFieldParser`. It has code that correctly handles quotes around the contents of columns.

Comment: I'm looking at exporting to CSV rather than importing though exporting from a C# DataTable, importing to MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, your question says "Importing From CSV"

Comment: My fault! I'm importing from CSV to MySQL, exporting from a DataTable in C# to CSV

Answer (score 0):

```
21,630,459,462,0,Test                         ,1996-08-02,14:45:04  ,2,Test   ,"DIY Test, Test                                                                       "
```

First thing you really need to do is trim those fields (or enclose them in quotes if you want to keep the spaces). Some readers have problems with spaces surrounding the seperator.

```
field.ToString().Contains(",") ? "\"" + field.ToString() + "\"" : field.ToString()
```

This won't work in all cases. Consider this:

```
"27" monitor, Samsung"
```

While your field is quoted (for the `,` inside), the quote inside the field needs to be escaped too. Normally by adding a second quote: `"27"" monitor, Samsung"`, or by using a `\` (linux style) - depending on the reader.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Danny. It's funny because the text is literally `DIY Test, Test`. There is no quotation mark in the sentence at all. It's just surrounded in quote marks due to the `,`. So now it looks like `"DIY Test, Test"` in the CSV file. When I import it into MySQL it looks like `DIY Test, Test"`, messing up the import completely.